# Q: tikz: How to add a colored callout box

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've drawn the diagram, but I don't know how to add a colored box.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (5*0.2,5*1.1);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (5*1.7,0);

\node [inner sep=2pt,label=left:$c$] (c) at ($ (A)!.5!(B) $) {};
\node [outer sep=2pt,label=right:$b$] (b) at ($ (A)!.36!(C) $) {};
\draw[thin,black,densely dashed](0,-1.2)--(B)(5*1.7,-1.2)--(C);
\draw[thin,stealth-stealth](0,-0.7)--++(5*1.7,0)node[fill=white,midway]{$a$};

\tkzFindAngle(B,A,C) \tkzGetAngle{at}

\coordinate (D) at ($(A)!6cm!\at/3:(B)$);
\tkzInterLL(A,D)(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{D}
\draw (D) node[below]{$D$};
\coordinate (E) at ($(A)!6cm!2*\at/3:(B)$);
\tkzInterLL(A,E)(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{E}
\draw (E) node[below]{$E$};
\node [inner sep=1pt,label=left:$\color{red}{u}$] (p) at ($ (A)!.57!(D) $) {};
\node [inner sep=1pt,label=left:$\color{blue}{v}$] (q) at ($ (A)!.55!(E) $) {};


\begin{scope}[thin]
\clip(B)--(A)--(D);
\draw[fill=gray!20!white,semithick](A)circle(5mm);
\draw[semithick](A)circle(5.8mm);
\node (I) [label=-90:$\theta$,outer sep=15pt] at (A) {};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[thin]
\clip(D)--(A)--(E);\draw[fill=gray!20!white,semithick](A)circle(5.4mm);
\node (J) [label=-80:$\theta$,outer sep=13pt] at (A) {};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[thin]
\clip(C)--(A)--(E);\draw[fill=gray!20!white,semithick](A)circle(5mm);\draw[semithick](A)circle(5.6mm);\draw[semithick](A)circle(6.2mm);
\node (K) [label=-47:$\theta$,outer sep=9pt] at (A) {};
\end{scope}

\draw[thick,red] (A)--(D);
\draw[thick,blue] (A)--(E);

\draw[thick] (A) node[above]{$A$}--
  (B) node[left]{$B$}--
  (C) node[right]{$C$}--(A);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Besides, are there any other beautiful boxes? Where can I search?

[image]

```
\begin{gather*} 
\color{black}{16S^2=(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)}\\ 
\\ 
\color{black}{\frac{a^2b^2-(b^2-c^2)^2}{bc^2}{\color{red}{u}}^3+3a^2{\color{red}{u}}^2-16S^2=0}\\  
\color{black}{\frac{a^2c^2-(b^2-c^2)^2}{b^2c}{\color{blue}{v}}^3+3a^2{\color{blue}{v}}^2-16S^2=0}\\ 
\end{gather*}
```

Comment: Hey! Have you heard of the tcolorbox-package yet? It's the most complete package for drawing boxes in all of LaTeX-land. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox

Comment: See `shapes.callouts` TikZ library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this does not look like a callout but just like box with a shadow.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (5*0.2,5*1.1);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (5*1.7,0);

\node [inner sep=2pt,label=left:$c$] (c) at ($ (A)!.5!(B) $) {};
\node [outer sep=2pt,label=right:$b$] (b) at ($ (A)!.36!(C) $) {};
\draw[thin,black,densely dashed](0,-1.2)--(B)(5*1.7,-1.2)--(C);
\draw[thin,stealth-stealth](0,-0.7)--++(5*1.7,0)node[fill=white,midway]{$a$};

\tkzFindAngle(B,A,C) \tkzGetAngle{at}

\coordinate (D) at ($(A)!6cm!\at/3:(B)$);
\tkzInterLL(A,D)(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{D}
\draw (D) node[below]{$D$};
\coordinate (E) at ($(A)!6cm!2*\at/3:(B)$);
\tkzInterLL(A,E)(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{E}
\draw (E) node[below]{$E$};
\node [inner sep=1pt,label=left:$\color{red}{u}$] (p) at ($ (A)!.57!(D) $) {};
\node [inner sep=1pt,label=left:$\color{blue}{v}$] (q) at ($ (A)!.55!(E) $) {};


\begin{scope}[thin]
\clip(B)--(A)--(D);
\draw[fill=gray!20!white,semithick](A)circle(5mm);
\draw[semithick](A)circle(5.8mm);
\node (I) [label=-90:$\theta$,outer sep=15pt] at (A) {};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[thin]
\clip(D)--(A)--(E);\draw[fill=gray!20!white,semithick](A)circle(5.4mm);
\node (J) [label=-80:$\theta$,outer sep=13pt] at (A) {};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[thin]
\clip(C)--(A)--(E);\draw[fill=gray!20!white,semithick](A)circle(5mm);
\draw[semithick](A)circle(5.6mm);\draw[semithick](A)circle(6.2mm);
\node (K) [label=-47:$\theta$,outer sep=9pt] at (A) {};
\end{scope}

\draw[thick,red] (A)--(D);
\draw[thick,blue] (A)--(E);

\draw[thick] (A) node[above]{$A$}--
  (B) node[left]{$B$}--
  (C) node[right]{$C$}--(A);

\node[fill=yellow,blur shadow={shadow xshift=-0.5ex},
    text width=20em,anchor=south west,rounded corners] at 
    ([xshift=2em]b.east)
    {\[16S^2=(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)\]
    \[\frac{a^2b^2-(b^2-c^2)^2}{bc^2}\textcolor{red}{u}^3+3a^2\textcolor{red}{u}^2-16S^2=0\]
    \[\frac{a^2c^2-(b^2-c^2)^2}{b^2c}\textcolor{blue}{v}^3+3a^2\textcolor{blue}{v}^2-16S^2=0\]
    ~};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but there is a clerical error. Coefficient of cubic term on v.

Comment: @user165013 Thanks! I am very bad at punching in texts from a screen shot. I fied this now but in general you will get much quicker an answer if you do not make those willing to write an answer type in texts from screen shots, but add the equations/text to the question.